# How to run a VBA code from a batch file?

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file, vbscript

I have an XLSX file that I modify to copy some data from one cell to another using the following VBA code.

I then convert this xlsx file to csv format. (I'm okay in doing this)

Since this xlsx file is replaced daily with a new file I need to find a way to run my VBA code from a batch file that I can schedule.

**My code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub copy_Cell_A4()

    Dim RowLocation As Long 'can hold over 32000 if over this many rows
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        RowLocation = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ws.Range("A4").Copy ws.Range("J6:J" & RowLocation)
        ws.Range("A2").Copy ws.Range("K6:K" & RowLocation)
        ws.Range("E2").Copy ws.Range("L6:L" & RowLocation)
    Next ws

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to put your code in another excel file or VBScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your code a bit and store the same in a .vbs script which will be a standalone script file so can be used independently.

Reference your excel file like this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim xlApp, xlBook
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user1\Desktop\samplefile.xlsx, 0, True)
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a VBScript to silently run the MACRO in your workbook.

In the code below, just replace the following parameters:

1. `"C:\YourFolderPath\"` - with your folder path, where you keep your Excel file with the code in it.
2. `"SO_VBScript.xlsm"` - modify to your Excel file where you keep your "copy_Cell_A4" `Sub` code.
3. `"copy_Cell_A4"` - this is the name of the `Sub` you have in your post.

**VBScript Code**

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp
Dim xlBook
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\YourFolderPath\SO_VBScript.xlsm", 0, True)
xlApp.Run "copy_Cell_A4"
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlBook.Save
xlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Finished"
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: @TontoDiablo have you tried running the above cde in VBScript?